# WP Ajax 400 Bad request. Ajax in Class and Method

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am new to **OOP PHP** so this is likely where I am going wrong.

Here is my simple class. It is called when I load the page and the additional jQuery works fine for sending the ajax request.

EDIT:
I have a new tab which I have created in the woocommerce account page. (knp_product_submission_content). This spits out some basic HTML. 
When the user clicks an icon on the page, the data from the form is submitted via ajax (just the value of the action input). This should then return the content from the callback.

```
/**************
Add the core js file in the main plugin file. 
*********************/
function knp_vendor_scripts(){  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'core', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/core.js', array(), false, true );
    wp_localize_script('core', 'vendor_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'knp_vendor_scripts' );

/**
* New class initiated in a woocommerce endpoint function
**/
function knp_product_submissions_content(){ 

  //Create the views object for fetching and displaying. 
  $views = new submission_views();         
  echo '<div class="ajax-container-div">';
     //response content should go here      
  echo '</div>';

}
add_action('woocommerce_account_product-submissions_endpoint', 'knp_product_submissions_content');

/**
* Get the data from the form
* the user has just clicked on
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.knpv_form_submit').on('click', function(){

    var formID = 
    jQuery(this).closest('form.knpv_ajax_form').attr('id');

    var data = jQuery('#'+formID).serialize();

    jQuery.post(vendor_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {

        jQuery('.ajax-container-div').html(response);

    });

  });

});

class submission_views{
    /**
    * Setup ajax action and callbacks
    */
    public function __construct(){
        //Get the form for a new submission
        add_action('wp_ajax_knpv_add_new_submission', array($this, 'knpv_add_new_submission_callback'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_knpv_add_new_submission', array($this, 'knpv_add_new_submission_callback'));
    }

    /**
    * Get the form html and send back 
    */ 
    public function knpv_add_new_submission_callback(){ 
        ob_start(); 
        ?>

        <section class="knp_vendor_submission_form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=3'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <?php 
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }
```

I am using this really just to replace some content on the page. It is triggered on click and the response I get back is

> 400 Bad Request

Am I placing add_action in the right place? How do I know if it is even seeing the callback function?

TIA

Comment: We need to see some more code to help: how are you enqueueing your JS? How are you making the ajax call?

Comment: More code that should help. @cabrerahector

Comment: If i take the add_aciton functions out of the class andput them in the the plugin file then the whole thing works.

Comment: Are you instantiating the `submission_views` class? If so, where and how?

Comment: This is added in knp_product_submissions_content()

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Chances are the class is being instantiated too late though which would explain why your hooks aren't being registered/run. Try hooking into [plugins_loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) instead and instantiate your class there.

Comment: This is the way I went with it and after a fair bit of house keeping in the plugin files its all working fine.

Answer (score 1):

you created the class but you did not create an object for that ! Please insert the following line into your main plugin file :

```
$ajax_handlers = new submission_views();
```

Comment: you put it in the wrong place, remove it from there and put it in the main file of the plugin

Comment: I will come back to answer this question. I've been pulled onto something else at work but will come back to this and answer / feedback today.